# Append dataframe to existing sheet in excel without modifying and save as another excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to use an existing excel as a template and appending the dataframe to it and want to save as another excel

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('desktop\Template.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('desktop\Template.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',datetime_format='m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

data_f1.to_excel(writer,'Tickets', startrow=1, header=False , index = False)
writer.save()
```

Also I am trying to change the representation of datetime object from pandas to excel in desired format , its not working with `openpyxl`

Comment: I'd recommend using `shutil.copyfile` and then editing the copied excel.

Comment: openpyxl lets you work directly with Pandas DataFrames.